# Naming convention for less than utf32

Tags: unicode

Unicode `UTF-32` values we can call codepoints, though I suppose even this is wrong since a single surrogate is itself a codepoint. UTF-8 can be called multi-byte or multi-octet. But what about `UTF-16` and `UCS-2`. They aren't exactly multi-byte since they deal in 2 bytes, and I think multi-word is more of a MS naming scheme.

What is a more accurate name to describe `UTF-32` codepoints that can be made up of bytes, as in `UTF-8` and words as in `UTF-16`?

Comment: I just call them variable-width encodings, as opposed to fixed-width encodings.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes This works when referring to a string, but what about single characters and an octet/word of those?

Comment: No, that works when referring to an encoding. Each individual byte (UTF-8) or 16-bit word (UTF-16) is called a *code unit*. To refer to the sequence of code units that encode a Unicode scalar value, the Unicode standard uses *minimal well-formed code unit subsequence*. When it's clear from context, I tend to just go with "code unit sequence", even though it isn't really accurate.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "code sequence" is something I often use, never thought about using "unit" though. I'm just looking for a suitable word to use in code comments. I feel char, word and codepoint/point are too specific. I suppose "unit" could be used in this instance.

Comment: @Waldermort: *Code units* refer to the individual elements used to encode a given Unicode *code point* in a given encoding. In UTF-7, it takes a variable number of 7-bit *code units* to encode a given *code point*. In UTF-8, it takes 1, 2, 3, or 4 8-bit *code units* to encode a single *code point*, depending on *code point* value. In UTF-16, it takes either 1 or 2 16-bit *code units* to encode a given *code point*, depending on if surrogates are needed. In UTF-32, it takes 1 32-bit *code unit* to encode a given *code point*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is 'code unit'.

Code points are simply integral values that may be assigned a character in a character set.

A code unit is a fixed width integer representation used in sequences to represent encoded text. UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are all encodings, and use 8, 16, and 32 bit code units respectively.

UTF-32 is unique among the three in that its code unit values are always exactly the code point values of the represented Unicode data.

---

'multi-byte' can appropriately be used to in reference to UTF-16. (And 'Unicode' can be used in reference to UTF-8; Microsoft's usage of the terminology is misleading on both counts.)

---

> a single surrogate is itself a codepoint.

Unicode classifies code point in the range [U+D800-U+DFFF] as surrogates. These code points are never used as such, however. They are reserved and cannot be used because UTF-16 cannot represent code points in this range; in order to represent such code points UTF-16 would use code units in the range [0xD800-0xDFFF], however UTF-16 uses code unit values in this range to represent code points above U+FFFF and therefore cannot use them to represent code points in the range [U+D800-U+DFFF].